# Interacting with subprocess while reading stdout and stderr in real time

Tags: python

I need to write a wrapper around a shell command that prints its stdout and stderr in real time back to stdout and stderr respectively, while also allowing the user to interact and send stdin to it, if the process prompts for input.

Note that `pexpect.interact()` almost solves the problem, except that it combines all stdout and stderr and sends it back to stdout. And there appears no way to stop it doing that.

What I have so far, is a method to read stdout and stderr from a process via `subprocess.Popen`:

```py
def _popen_command(
    command: List[str]
) -> None:
    """
    Run a shell command with Popen line by line
    in real time without redirecting stdout or stderr.
    """

    with subprocess.Popen(
        command,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE
    ) as proc:

        selector = selectors.DefaultSelector()
        selector.register(proc.stdout, selectors.EVENT_READ)  
        selector.register(proc.stderr, selectors.EVENT_READ)  

        eof = False
        while not eof:
            for key, _ in selector.select():
                data = key.fileobj.read1(1).decode()  

                if not data:
                    eof = True

                if key.fileobj is proc.stdout:
                    print(data, end="")
                else:
                    print(data, end="", file=sys.stderr)
```

I don't believe an answer exists with all of these features exists in Stack Overflow: handles stdout, stderr, in real time, line by line, and prints them back to stdout, stderr, respectively, and also allows arbitrary interaction with stdin.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: If you just want stdout and stderr to be printed out as you have shown, then I don't understand why you are even specifying `stdout=subprocess.PIPE,,stderr=subprocess.PIPE`. But if you are executing a shell command, I would think you would need to specify `shell=True` and the input command can be just a string instead of a list of strings.